# How to set submenu items to Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Here is the menu I am working at:

[image]

I have added submenu items under a menu item.

[image]

But it does not work at all. How can I add submenu items? Or at least how do I check if the menu I am using can do that?

Here is the page I am working at: http://darnicgaz.md/?lang=en_us

Comment: is it same menu are you updating ? please check it once

Comment: yes, I've edited other items in menu. 100% same menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i have tested your site. submenu displaying fine in mobile and display none in web view.

**style.css line no 1110**

```
#primary-menu ul ul, #primary-menu ul li .mega-menu-content { 
display:none
}
```

remove that `display :none` from this style

Comment: thank you, thank helped. but damn, its so ugly, gotta fix it now)